# display inline listings (li) from right in HTML

Tags: html, css, inline, floating

Here is the scenario:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.menu li {display:inline}
```

The results would be:

```
1  2  3
```

but I want to display them from right to left:

```
3  2  1
```

How can I achieve this please?

Comment: What `<li>` is doing within `<div>`, where's your `<ul>`s? )

Comment: Thanks @Pow-Ian, surely I can but in this case I was looking for some other way.

Comment: @raina77ow Sorry I didn't know it's necessary because it works fine this way. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul {
    width: 50px;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}​
```

Also, you can't have `li` being the direct descendents of a `div`. Use `ul` or `ol`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DLqce/)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding float: right to the CSS

```
.menu li {display:inline; float: right;}
```

You may need to add additional restrictions to prevent the list flying to the right side of the page

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to wrap your `<li>`s with a `<ul>` tag, not a `<div>`.

```
li {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}
ul{
  float: left;
}
```

​[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/hKWJx/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

CSS Code:

```
.menu li {display:inline}
.menu ul{direction:rtl;}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AJs29/)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you re-arrange them? Changing the order of list elements is not a matter of presentation so it shouldn't be handled by CSS, but by HTML.

By the way you forgot to wrap your li's inside a a ul tag.

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

using the new `reversed` attribute of HTML5, you can tell the browser that the numbering for the list items should display in descending order, instead of the default ascending.

```
<ol reversed>  
    <li>List item one</li>  
    <li>List item two</li>  
    <li>List item three</li>  
    <li>List item four</li>  
    <li>List item five</li>  
</ol>
```